# Pandas how to transpose the data and add the column name

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas I'm transposing the data and want to name the column.

My current data is:

```
    alpha   bravo    charlie
0   public  private  public
1   prodA   prodB    prodB
2   100     200      300
```

After transposing and renaming the columns, the output is:

```
df.transpose()
df.columns = ["category", "product", "price"]

    category    product price
alpha   public  prodA   100
bravo   private prodB   200
charlie public  prodB   300
```

How can I have the expected output like:

```
company category product price
alpha   public   prodA   100
bravo   private  prodB   200
charlie public   prodB   300
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just setup the index first, then tanspose the dataframe

```
df.index = pd.Index(['category','product','price'],name='company')
df.T

company category product price
alpha     public   prodA   100
bravo    private   prodB   200
charlie   public   prodB   300
```

Answer (score 3):

First set the index name via `df.index.set_names`, then apply `reset_index`:

```
df.index = df.index.set_names('company')
df.columns = ['category', 'product', 'price']
df = df.reset_index()

#    company category product price
# 0    alpha   public   prodA   100
# 1    bravo  private   prodB   200
# 2  charlie   public   prodB   300
```

Answer (score 1):

You can us rename_axis and reset_index:

```
(
    df.T
    .set_axis(["category", "product", "price"], axis=1, inplace=False)
    .rename_axis('company',axis=0)
    .reset_index()
)

Out[124]: 
   company category product price
0    alpha   public   prodA   100
1    bravo  private   prodB   200
2  charlie   public   prodB   300
```

If you would like to keep company as index:

```
(
    df.T
    .set_axis(["category", "product", "price"], axis=1, inplace=False)
    .rename_axis('company',axis=0)
)
Out[125]: 
        category product price
company                       
alpha     public   prodA   100
bravo    private   prodB   200
charlie   public   prodB   300
```

Comment: Allen wouldn't be easier if you reset the index in the beginning in the first option i.e `df.T.reset_index().set_axis('company category product price'.split(),1,inplace=False)`

Comment: @Dark, I wasn't sure if the OP wants company as a column or index. You are right, it could be a bit easier if he wants column.